# have no access to javax.naming.Context

Tags: jboss, osgi, jndi

I'm working with JBOSS AS 7.1.1. I have registered a datasource and I try to access it throught a JNDI in my OSGI bundle like :

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();

DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup(datasource_jndi_name);
```

but when i deploy my bundle to AS i get an exception: ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.Context.

Context is defined in rt.jar, so i tried to wrap it in bundle and deploy it to AS but got the same error.

I tried to replace Context with InitialContext and got ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.InitialContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yepp, OSGi isolates that away. You an `Import-Package` for `javax.naming`. In addition you should probably use `JNDIContextManager#newInitialContext()` to create the initial context.

Comment: i tried import javax.naming package and get the same error.
i thought that it is a jboss bug

Comment: problem resolved by deleting javax.naming import declaration in manifest and adding it again.